# PowerShell DownloadFile for File name Changing every day

Tags: powershell, automation, filenames, webclient, webrequest

Code below to download a file from website:
https://www.mcafee.com/enterprise/en-us/downloads/security-updates.html

[File being downloaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k4RNI.png)

However, the file name is changing every day. For example: 'mediumepo4981dat.zip' today and 'mediumepo4980dat.zip' yesterday.

How can I create a script which I can run daily which works dynamically?

```
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::ServerCertificateValidationCallback = {$true}
$uri = "https://download.nai.com/products/datfiles/med/mediumepo4981dat.zip"
$filename = "C:\DownloadTest\mediumepo4981dat.zip"
$wc = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$wc.UseDefaultCredentials = $true
$wc.DownloadFile($uri, $filename)
```

Please let me know if you need any further clarification.

Note: Looking for a solution without Invoke-WebRequest as that does not work in my current environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$uri  = [uri] "https://download.nai.com/products/datfiles/med"
$wr   = Invoke-WebRequest $uri
$file = $wr.ParsedHtml.getElementsByTagName('a') |
    Select-Object -Last 1 -ExpandProperty TextContent
$toDownload = [uri]::new($uri, $file)
```

is missing trailing '/' in $uri.
It should be

```
  $uri  = [uri] "https://download.nai.com/products/datfiles/med/"
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems like we can assume that the **last file listed is always the newest**, can't confirm if this will always be true it may change at some point. For the time being, this is how you can get the last file:

```
$uri  = [uri] "https://download.nai.com/products/datfiles/med"
$wr   = Invoke-WebRequest $uri
$file = $wr.ParsedHtml.getElementsByTagName('a') |
    Select-Object -Last 1 -ExpandProperty TextContent
$toDownload = [uri]::new($uri, $file)
```

Now you can combine this with the rest of your script:

```
$filename = Join-Path 'C:\DownloadTest\' -ChildPath $file
$wc = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$wc.UseDefaultCredentials = $true
$wc.DownloadFile($toDownload.AbsoluteUri, $filename)
```

Note that this will work only in Windows PowerShell.

Comment: Thank you Santiago. The code you provided looks great but unfortunately I am struggling to get Invoke-WebRequest to work as I receive error below:

 Invoke-WebRequest : The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.
At line:3 char:2
+  Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://mcafee.com
+  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand

Comment: This was the reason to resort to DownloadFile which is working in my environment. I was thinking of some form of a wild card like mediumepo????dat.zip where ? is any number would work but I am not sure how to configure that. Let me know if you know a way without invoke-webrequest. Otherwise, thank you for your help. I appreciate your time.

Comment: I tried many different addresses but nothing work, might be a fault in the servers in my company or access restriction